# Column-Span: all not supporting in CKEditor

Tags: html, css, firefox

In the Firefox, the `column-span: all` not working inside of the CKEditor. Its working fine in the Chrome browser.

How to get the same output in the Firfox (like chrome result)?

**Code:**

```
<div style="display:block;-webkit-column-count:2;-moz-column-count:2;column-count:2;column-gap:17px;">
<h1>Header 1</h1>
<p>Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample  
</p>
<p>Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample
Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample 
Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample 
Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample 
Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample  
</p>
<div style="display: table;column-span:all;-webkit-column-span: all;-moz-column-span: all;width:100%">
    <table style="width:100%" border="1px">
        <tbody>
            <tr style="height:15.0pt"><td>Column 1</td>
                <td>Column 1</td>
                <td>Column 2</td>
                <td>Column 3</td>
                <td>Column 4</td>
                <td>Column 5</td>
                <td>Column 6</td>
                <td>Column 7</td>
                <td>Column 8</td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="height:15.0pt"><td>Column 1</td>
                <td>Column 1</td>
                <td>Column 2</td>
                <td>Column 3</td>
                <td>Column 4</td>
                <td>Column 5</td>
                <td>Column 6</td>
                <td>Column 7</td>
                <td>Column 8</td>
            </tr><tr style="height:15.0pt"><td>Column 1</td>
                <td>Column 1</td>
                <td>Column 2</td>
                <td>Column 3</td>
                <td>Column 4</td>
                <td>Column 5</td>
                <td>Column 6</td>
                <td>Column 7</td>
                <td>Column 8</td>
            </tr><tr style="height:15.0pt"><td>Column 1</td>
                <td>Column 1</td>
                <td>Column 2</td>
                <td>Column 3</td>
                <td>Column 4</td>
                <td>Column 5</td>
                <td>Column 6</td>
                <td>Column 7</td>
                <td>Column 8</td>
            </tr><tr style="height:15.0pt"><td>Column 1</td>
                <td>Column 1</td>
                <td>Column 2</td>
                <td>Column 3</td>
                <td>Column 4</td>
                <td>Column 5</td>
                <td>Column 6</td>
                <td>Column 7</td>
                <td>Column 8</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<h1>Header 2</h1>
<p>Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample </p>
<p>Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample Sample </p>
```

**Screenshot from Chrome**

[image: Output from Chrome]

**Screenshot from Firefox**

[image: Output from Firefox]

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with Ckeditor. Even outside Ckeditor it will give same error. You took wrong values in your first `<div>`'s column count attribute. It is just 2 there while in your inner `<div>` its all. Replace the column count values of your first div to auto or all and see the magic. I did it for you. Your code should look like

```
<body>
   <div style="display:block;-webkit-column-count:auto;-moz-column-count:auto;column-count:auto;column-gap:17px;">
<h1>Header 1</h1>
```

just do it and see the difference :)